# Find line number of replaced key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, replace

How do I get the line number of replaced key value?
currently functions are different for it, how do i combine it to have line number at the time of replacing the string.

```
filedata= is a path of file. In which i need to replace strings.

old_new_dict = {'hi':'bye','old':'new'}

def replace_oc(file):
    lines = file.readlines()

    line_number = None
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line_number = i + 1
        break
    return line_number

def replacee(path, pattern):
    for key, value in old_new_dict.items():
        if key in filedata:
            print("there")
            filedata = filedata.replace(key, value)
        else:
            print("not there")
```

Comment: What is `filedata`? Please edit your code with a definition for `filedata` so that the code snippet becomes a [mre].

Comment: There are a lot of very basic errors in this code such that it's impossible to run it and it's difficult to determine what the intent is based on the code alone.  If you're completely stuck and need help getting the code to work, you should write an English-language description of what the code *should* be doing so that it's possible to suggest code changes that will get you closer to your intent.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the question. thank you @Samwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break down the filedata into lines to check for the words to replace before doing the actual replacements.  For example:

```
filedata = """The quick brown fox
jumped over
the lazy dogs
and the cow ran away 
from the fox"""

old_new_dict = {"dogs":"cats", "crazy":"sleeping","fox":"cow"}

for key,value in old_new_dict.items():
    lines = [i for i,line in enumerate(filedata.split("\n"),1) if key in line]
    if lines:
        filedata = filedata.replace(key,value)
        print(key,"found at lines",*lines)
        
    else:
        print(key,"is not there")
```

output:

```
# dogs found at lines 3
# crazy is not there
# fox found at lines 1 5

print(filedata)

The quick brown cow
jumped over
the lazy cats
and the cow ran away 
from the cow
```